# Height of 100% and Doctype

Tags: css, internet-explorer, height, doctype

I have a little problem with IE, doctype and height 100%.

In fact, I have a page container with a height of 100%  but I think my doctype line is bad it don't run on IE and only run on chrome etc. if I delete the doctype line. What is the good doctype for use this things?

I have test all the doctype possible, the problem can come of something other?

Thx

Comment: I'm afraid your description is a little vague.  Perhaps you could post the actual code of your project for review?

Comment: Also, which version of IE do you have problems with? Behaviour of IE differs greatly between versions.

Comment: I have a container who must take 100% of the height window. How can I do? On chrome, if I delete the doctype it run, but I don't want delete this line. So what is the good practice? (It's less vague?)

Comment: Consider editing your question to include the doctype code (you could have made a typo) CSS used and the HTML for the document you are having trouble with. Help us to help you :)

Comment: Here's a simple and clear explanation of the DOCTYPE issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/32215263/3597276